# How to force user to input positive integer starting value within a certain range

Tags: c

How do I fix my code so that if the starting value is inputed as a negative integer it will ask for another starting value. Also what is the best way to go about calculating the difference every time both the starting and ending values are inputed.

```
void inputs(int* starting_value, int* ending_value)
    {
      int temp; // switch for while loop

      temp = 0; // enter while loop

      while(temp == 0)
      {

        printf("Enter starting value of range -> ");
        scanf("%d", starting_value);

        do
        {
          printf("Error! Starting value must be non-negative!!\n");
          printf("\nEnter starting value of range -> ");
          scanf("%d", starting_value);
        } while(starting_value < 0); // if input is negative

        printf("Enter ending value of range -> ");
        scanf("%d", ending_value);

        temp = 1; // leave while loop

        if (ending_value - starting_value > 5000000) // if the total difference is less than 5000000
        {
          temp = 0; // restart while loop
          printf("\n\nError! The maximum difference between start and end is 5000000\n\n");
        }

      }
    }
```

Comment: @chqrlie I changed that variable to switch after I pasted my code in here I I forgot it was already a function, I changed it back to what I had.

Answer (score 0):

change your do-while to just while when checking the input, if the user enters 1 the first time he'll still go through that retry logic.

The best way is probably to get both inputs at once, then subtract them.

```
printf("Enter start and end variables\n");
scanf("%d %d", &start, &end);

while((start < 0) || (end < 0)){ //You can also throw a max range check here too
  printf("Enter start and end variables\n");
  printf("Make SURE neither value is negative\n");
  scanf("%d %d", &start, &end);
}

//subtract or do whatever else after both inputs are non negative
```